# Thinner plot line in Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot

I have approximately 4000 random lines to plot on axes: `[0 1000 0 1000]`
The standard line thickness of the plot function is too thick to be able to see the white spaces in between my lines. So what I see is a basically a solid square. I played with the `linewidth` parameter:

```
plot(P(:,1),P(:,2),'linewidth',.0001);
```

but its still too thick. Is there anything else I can do to get a thinner line?

EDIT:

I was able to get much better results by using:

```
set(gcf,'GraphicsSmoothing','off')
```

Any other ideas that I can try?

Comment: what about just plotting a sample of the lines?

Comment: @Stedy can't do that. The lines all come together to recreate an image

Comment: What's the screen size/resolution of your monitor? You won't be able to go below 1 pixel for the rendered line width, otherwise it will just disappear. Perhaps you should bin your line data and create a plot of line density?

Comment: @gnovice Let's say I am already at 1 pixel line width and I am still not happy. Changing the pixel density/spacing of the line itself would give the illusion of thinner lines right? Is there a convenient way to do this in Matlab?

Comment: @MikeJamesJohnson: I believe you're referring to the ['LineStyle' property](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/primitiveline-properties.html). Changing that *might* help, but it only has 4 options: solid, dashed, dotted, and dash-dotted.

Comment: the linestyle property didn't work out too well, but what I ended up doing was using : `p1.Color(4) = 0.5;` for my plot, `p1` which changes the transparency of the line. This actually made it look infinitely times better!

Comment: Glad you solved it, you should write this up as an answer to make it easier for others with the same issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could also try to export the figure as an high resolution image (e.g. 300 or more dpi) using the 3rd party `export_fig` function (https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23629-export-fig) or the matlab built-in figure export function.

When you export the figure as a high resolution figure, the lines might appear thinner than in you Matlab figure window.

Comment: Yes this also worked very well !
For others that may be viewing this answer for help, I also recommend trying my above suggestions of playing with transparency by setting the t coordinate of the`color` vector: `[r g b t]` and also by turning the graphicsSmoothing setting on the figure off. Thank you